# Trying to express the frequency of ones activity

Tags: grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

If I say...

> "you're almost always on call"

Is it a right form of expressing your little knowledge about the matter. In this case, I'm talking about the person who's not close (in relationship or friendship) to me.

Comment: Yes; if I understand your question right, "almost always" can be used in conversation to mean "quite often". For example, [parent, to hungry teenager]: _"You're almost always eating!"_ That doesn't mean the adolescent is literally eating 20 hours per day; it simply means the teen eats more often than his astonished parent.

Comment: Could you try to explain "expressing your slight knowledge of one who's not close," because I'm confused. As for "almost always" it's ok, if you mean "usually", normally".

Comment: The person is not close to my but i notice his phone is mostly on call waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first discuss the fragment you've posted in your question:

> you're almost always **on call**

The phrase *on call* is idiomatic, it means *on standby*. It usually means someone is not at work, but that person is ready to go to work at a moment's notice in case of an emergency. Firemen, doctors, and plumbers are example of people who might be on call, particularly during times outside of normal work hours, such as evenings, nights, and weekends.

Now let's discuss the phrase you've used in your comment:

> The person is not close to my but I notice his phone is mostly on **call waiting**.

*Call waiting* is a telephone service. Google indicates that call waiting is "a service whereby someone making a telephone call is notified of an incoming call and is able to place the first call on hold while answering the second."

Suppose Alice calls Bob, and then Charlie calls Alice. Because Alice has call waiting, she gets notified that someone else is calling, and she can accept that call. Then, either Bob or Charlie will be *on hold* while Alice talks to the other one.

The phrase "almost always on call waiting" makes no sense in the context that you describe. If Charlie is "on call waiting," that means Charlie is calling Alice, and Alice is being notified that Charlie is calling her while she is talking to someone else. It's a very temporary status; I don't know how you could know someone is "on call waiting" if they are not nearby.

I think what you are really trying to say is something along these lines:

> *You are almost always **on the phone***.
>   *You are almost always **taking calls***.
>   *Your phone is almost always busy; people are calling you all the time*.
>   *It is very hard to reach you over the phone*.

You haven't given very much information about what you are trying to express, so it's hard to answer your question any more than that.

When you ask questions in the future, try not to make them so terse. If you provide more information and clarification, it will be easier to figure out what you are trying to ask.

As for expressing the frequency of something, though, you can indeed use "almost always" to mean "very often" – such hyperbole is something native speakers do *all the time*.

Comment: Thanks  so much J.R. i appreciate the corrections above. The sentence was meant to convey the meaning as you have clarified in your correction statement "you're  almost always on the phone or youre are almost always taking calls". What i really wanted to know was the phrase, "almost always". Thanks